# По поводу .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Интересуют два вопроса касающиеся файла .htaccess:

1. Запретил доступ ко всем в файлам в папке, но через дерективу Files разрешил доступ к index.php:

<Files index.php>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>

Дело в том что это работает только если ссылка на страницу прямая, т.е с явно указанным расширением. А для ссылок вида site.net/folder/ это не распространяется - пишет доступ запрещён. Хотя клиент по-прежнему обращается к index.php. Можно ли это исправить?

2. Как разрешить доступ клиенту ко всем папкам css и js которые лежат в других папках? Т.е есть тот самый index.php и вместе с ним лежат папки, допустим "folder" и "folder 2". В каждой из этих папок лежит папка css и/или js. Как прописать разрешения для предоставления доступа клиенту к этим папкам?

Comment: С другой стороны, даже и убирать ничего не надо. Зачем вообще это нужно, "Запретил доступ ко всем в файлам в папке"? Какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Дело в том что этот index.php является конструктором страницы. В зависимости с какого устройства зашёл пользователь и в зависимости от переданных параметров этот файл строит страницу. Как раз те файлы и папки, кроме тех самых css и js не должны быть доступны по клиенту по отдельности. Они только для подключения к index.php

Comment: Что значит "не должны"? С какой стати клиент будет обращаться к этим файлам "по отдельности"? А даже если и обратится, то  что такого ужасного случится в этом случае? И если уж на то пошло, то какая проблема положить эти файлы в отдельную папку и уже только её и закрыть со спокойной душой, без всяких исключений?